# which.min() returning two numbers

Tags: r, igraph

I need the position of the smallest value in my vector (degrees in a graph, got from function degree()). I use the which.min().

However as the vector itself is "anotated", I get two values - the name of the node and the position in the vector (which I have no idea why they are not in the right order) - here node "23" has the smallest degree and it is in the 40th position in the vector. They appear on top of each other and I cannot figure out how to separate them.

I need to use just the name of the node for further applications. I couldn't find any question about this issue.

```
> degs
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 34 35 36 38 39 40 41 33 23 37 42 43 
14 25 31 17 25 11 26 21 23 25 24 17 13 20 12 15  7 15 28 18  9 17  8  7  7  7 14 19 12 17 19 10 19 20 19 10  7 11 12  6  8 12 13

> which.min(degs)
23 
40
```

Comment: Just use `which.min(unname(test))` if the names bother you.

Answer (score 1):

The top number is just the name of the value and you can ignore it, see?

```
> c("23" = 40)
23 
40
```

Comment: Try `unname(which.min(...))` to remove the name.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I usually just ignore it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the name of the node, you can use

```
names(which.min(degs))
```

Output will be "23".